# Pass prop value to dynamically built click event in svg Vue.js component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, svg, events

I'm creating a map component from a JSON array and adding a click event handler to each item. The click event will toggle the css style to colour the item. This works fine. What I'd like to do though, is to choose the colour to toggle from a prop. However, the value is only set when the function is created, not when it fires. I'm not sure how to get to the current value of the prop 'pickColour' when doing the click event function. Alternatively, how do I find the equivalent of the 'this.node' if I use an arrow function?

This is my component,

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{pickColour}}</div>
    <div :id="svgId" class="svg-container"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import myMap from "../assets/MainMap";
export default {
  name: "VenueMapComponent",
  props: {
    pickColour: String,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      svgId: "myMap",
      mapAttr: {
        viewBoxWidth: 1000,
        viewBoxHeight: 2500,
        imageWidth: 1000,
        imageHeight: 2500,
      },
      svgContainer: null,
    };
  },
  mounted: function () {
    this.generateVenueMap();
  },
  methods: {
    generateVenueMap: function () {
      const vue = this;
      const mapData = myMap.g.path;
      const svgContainer = vue
        .$svg("myMap")
        .size("100%", "100%")
        .viewbox(-200, 0, vue.mapAttr.viewBoxWidth, vue.mapAttr.viewBoxHeight);
      vue.svgContainer = svgContainer;
      mapData.forEach((pathObj) => {
        vue.generatePath(svgContainer, pathObj);
      });
    },
    generatePath: function (svgCont, pathObj) {
      const vue = this;
      const attrs = {
        title: pathObj["-title"],
        "map-id": pathObj["-id"],
      };
      const element = svgCont.path(pathObj["-d"]).attr(attrs);

      let mapId = "";
      let title = "";
      element.click(function () {
        mapId = this.node.attributes["map-id"].value;
        title = this.node.attributes["title"].value;

        // need a way to set string from property
        this.node.classList.toggle("def");
        ////

        vue.$emit("map-clicked", { mapId, title });
      });
      element.mouseover(function () {
        mapId = this.node.attributes["map-id"].value;
        title = this.node.attributes["title"].value;
        this.node.classList.add("on");
        //     vue.$emit("map-over", { mapId, title });
      });
      element.mouseout(function () {
        mapId = this.node.attributes["map-id"].value;
        title = this.node.attributes["title"].value;
        this.node.classList.remove("on");
        //     vue.$emit("map-over", { mapId, title });
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>
path {
  fill: #adaf93;
  stroke: white;
}
path.on {
  fill: rgb(221, 221, 103);
  stroke: rgb(128, 98, 16);
}
path.abc {
  fill: rgb(47, 80, 48);
  stroke: rgb(25, 100, 71);
}
path.abc.on {
  fill: rgb(102, 182, 104);
  stroke: rgb(25, 100, 71);
}
path.def {
  fill: rgb(22, 36, 156);
  stroke: rgb(25, 100, 71);
}
path.def.on {
  fill: rgb(94, 92, 216);
  stroke: rgb(25, 100, 71);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, I did it right after posting! The arrow function was the way to go, if anyone else needs it,

```html
element.click(() => {
    mapId = element.node.attributes["map-id"].value;
    title = element.node.attributes["title"].value;

        // need a way to set string from prop value
    element.node.classList.toggle(this.pickColour);

});
```